# PHP - Error when accessing object property $id

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial about how to make register form with database connection  but for some reason the code does not work for me. I do not know what I am doing wrong so maybe someone can point it out for me.

This is the code on the `User.php` file:

```
<?php
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}
?>
```

Getting this error back:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/rd-website/classes/User.php on line 37

Line 37 is: `Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);`

Any help?

Comment: show the method `data()`. It's returning an (standardClass) Object, which doesn't contain `$id`. But you ask for it.

Comment: and seeing the `Hash::make` I'm not so sure if you should follow this tutorial. might be outdated. These days we use password_verify() in this situation.

Comment: [Passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: is it because the ('id')  in                                                                      public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

Comment: yes the tutorial is outdated but in some way i like the way the guy explain what he is doing, i'm a noob at this but had to make the start at some point. i had some troubles with the salt function because  PHP 7.2.2 work different know this days.

Comment: The error means that the object returned by `$this->data()` doesn't contain an `id` property. That's the object that comes from `$data->first()` in `find()`.

Comment: public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If it's important information, put it in the question.

Comment: Did you change anything from the first comment with that function?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to your class that's used for database queries.

Comment: No it's still the same code

Comment: Is there an `id` column in the `users` table?

Comment: i can register new users on the database using the register form and i can check all the data in phpMyAdmin, i don;t really need the option to log in with id i just want it to work so i can go on to the next step but i want to understand what i'm doing wrong so i'm gonna read a bit more about returning object.

Comment: yes there is an id column in the users table

Comment: Hi Nic3500 this is post with the right code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error undefined property: stdClass:: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778902/error-undefined-property-stdclass-id)

Comment: yeah that's true i ask it twice, since i already solved this error i'm gonna remove 1 of the questions in a couple minutes

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i had the column named "ID" in the users table in the database, while in the User.php file it was written as "id".

Since Mysql is case insensitive if you are running on Windows that wouldn't be a problem or give any errors back, but for some Unix systems it's case sensitive, I run Kali-Linux so that was giving a error back.

I just changed the column "ID" to "id" in the database, as it was the easiest thing to do for this time and now the code works perfectly.

If you are looking for a permanent solution then you would have to change the "my.cnf" file,

under LAMPP/XAMPP... :

/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

stand alone mysql server :

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

with this line (lower_case_table_names = 1) You can change either to = 0,1 or 2 but that depends on your system and your needs.

After that you would need to restart the service again.